# Probabilistic model with $xyz \to max$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, partial-derivative

Can somebody give me a probabilistic model such that $x,y,z$ are probabilities, $xyz \to max$ and $x+y+z=1$, please? I've done at the university how to calculate the minimal surface of a box of volume $1$, using partial derivatives, but I have no idea how to make it with probabilities and what model to chose.

Comment: maybe $x=y=z=1/3$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's for the box problem. But it's different from the one with probabilities

Comment: You just need to impose non negativity constraints.

Consider the probability space $([0,1]^3,\mathcal B([0,1]^3),\lambda^3)$.

Then maximising $xyz$ subject to $x+y+z=1$ $x,y,z\geq 0$ is the same as maximising the probability measure $\lambda^3([0,x]\times[0,y]\times[0,z])=(x-0)\cdot(y-0)\cdot(z-0)=\lambda([0,x])\cdot\lambda([0,y])\cdot\lambda([0,z])=xyz$ (where $x,y,z,$ are probabilities so they are non-negative) subject to $x+y+z=1$.

Comment: I need a real life example